# Inner join query not working?

Tags: php

I have two tables one is order and the second is items and one common column order_no  so I used inner join query for fetching data on the basis of order_no but only the last matched record is fetched, so can anybody please tell me what is the problem in my query.

```
 $q="SELECT * FROM `items` INNER JOIN `order` ON  items.order_no=order.order_no";
 $result1= mysql_query($q,$this->_current_connection); 
 if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0){
 while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result1))
 {
     $arr=$row;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting your variable each time in a loop & thus you are getting only the last record, so just change,

```
$arr=$row;
```

to

```
$arr[]=$row;
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the array to the current `$row` in the iteration. Try this:

```
$arr = array();
while(...)
{
    array_push($arr, $row);
}
```

then you can iterate your array like so:

```
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to keep $arr as array not just simple variable. Try with this,

```
   $q="SELECT * FROM `items` INNER JOIN `order` ON  items.order_no=order.order_no";
   $result1= mysql_query($q,$this->_current_connection); 
   $arr = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result1))
        {
            $arr[]=$row;

        }
  print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to store your result in array.so you can use

```
 $arr[]=$row;
```

instead of

```
$arr=$row;
```